# Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.lang

Tags: java

I have a working jar lets call is `myapp.jar` and I want to leverage `jaotc`

```
jaotc --output myapp.so --jar myapp.jar
```

and I get the following error

```
Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.lang
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jdk.aot@11/jdk.tools.jaotc.Main.run(Main.java:136)
    at jdk.aot@11/jdk.tools.jaotc.Main.run(Main.java:102)
    at jdk.aot@11/jdk.tools.jaotc.Main.main(Main.java:81)
```

I did not declare any package named `java.lang` but of course I had to import classes from `java.lang` so my jar can work

I am using java 11.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you take a very simple HelloWorld.java, put it in a jar, and run jaotc on it? If so, please post that code. If HelloWorld.java doesn't give that problem, then the problem is in your source code, and you first need to figure out which class is causing the problem (by reduction) and then post that code here.